# Python : How to find in set of rows, one element is less than 1 and other is greater than 1?

Tags: python, pandas

I am scratching my head to figure out how I can do something like this.

I have a data frame which looks like this...

```
                A           B           C           D           E
1/2/2012 9:18   0.997558702 1.001294498 1.004264524 1.002337408 1.003628447
1/2/2012 9:19   1.004805553 1.001939237 1.002523232 1.001323543 1.003615329
1/2/2012 9:20   1.001151359 1.001290323 0.997728668 0.999937057 1
1/2/2012 9:21   1.001680821 1.003221649 1.001661232 1.000220313 1.003746398
1/2/2012 9:22   0.998454473 0.998715478 0.998095823 0.996286973 0.996985357
1/2/2012 9:23   0.996461899 0.99903537  1.00055388  0.999778915 0.997408207
1/2/2012 9:24   1.002174781 0.999034438 1.000492065 1.001232033 0.997978923
1/2/2012 9:25   0.999379982 1.00064433  0.998708963 1.000063103 0.999855345
```

I want to find out rows where 
[image: sets where one element is > 1 and other is < 1 or reverse]
It does not matter of the order of <1 or >1. Though it is important that the comparison is within same column and for consecutive times. I want to count all such occurrences by column for a dataframe

so output something like

```
      A B C D E 
index 4 2 5 4 1
```

I tried to think in looping over and just keep adding, but somehow think there should be better way to select from data frame.

This question is answered but as John suggested including psuedo code and column names.
    for each row if row < 1 and row.shift(1) > 1 or row > 1 and row.shift(1) < 1
        count

What I was trying to check is if I can avoid checking it both ways, because essentially its finding +ve -ve combination either ways in a column.

P.S>> I am checking mean reversion tendency of this dataset.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What do the red boxes mean?  We need to be a lot more rigorous in how we define the operation here, and what is the meaning of the output (are those row numbers?  column numbers?).

Comment: Let me explain it in different way - red boxes are the pairs obtained by where element > 1 and next element in the same column is < 1 or element is < 1 and next element in the same column is > 1. The output is sum of such pairs column wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before trying anything clever, I find it helps to spell out the straightforward version.  Using only boolean comparisons, `shift`, and the fact we can sum boolean columns to get the number of Trues because `int(True) == 1`, we can do:

```
>>> (((df < 1) & (df.shift() > 1)) | ((df > 1) & (df.shift() < 1))).sum()
0    4
1    2
2    5
3    4
4    1
dtype: int64
```

Which works with boolean frames looking like

```
>>> (df < 1) & (df.shift() > 1)
                   0      1      2      3      4

1/2/2012 9:18  False  False  False  False  False
1/2/2012 9:19  False  False  False  False  False
1/2/2012 9:20  False  False   True   True  False
1/2/2012 9:21  False  False  False  False  False
1/2/2012 9:22   True   True   True   True   True
1/2/2012 9:23  False  False  False  False  False
1/2/2012 9:24  False  False  False  False  False
1/2/2012 9:25   True  False   True  False  False
```

and I think is relatively easy to read.

---

A somewhat slicker version -- although, to be honest, probably too slick for its own good -- might be something like

```
>>> s = np.sign(df - 1)
>>> (s == -s.shift()).sum()
0    4
1    2
2    5
3    4
4    1
dtype: int64
```

but it's harder to see that this does what it's supposed to.  (I wrote it, and I'm only about 85% confident.)

Comment: The last version that you shared is what I was aiming for.. it helps greatly...thanks. I'll test it and make sure it works 100%